# Python dict to reformat data for required use

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need an help in code refactoring i have written the code and works fine.
but i've been using lot of code to get his achieved

I am using Python 2.7 version.
Any input on this will be great.

```
# source data:
car_info =[
    {'car': 'benz1', 'drive_mode': ['electric']},
    {'car': 'benz2', 'drive_mode': ['electric']},
    {'car': 'benz3', 'drive_mode': ['electric']},
    {'car': 'benz4', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw1', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw2', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw3', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw3', 'drive_mode': []}
  ]

# output format needed:
{'electric': ['benz1', 'benz2', 'benz3'], 'petrol': ['benz4', 'bmw1', 'bmw2', 'bmw3']}
```

Code i have tired so far and working one.

```
from collections import defaultdict
# source data:
car_info =[
    {'car': 'benz1', 'drive_mode': ['electric']},
    {'car': 'benz2', 'drive_mode': ['electric']},
    {'car': 'benz3', 'drive_mode': ['electric']},
    {'car': 'benz4', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw1', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw2', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
    {'car': 'bmw3', 'drive_mode': ['petrol']},
  {'car': 'bmw3', 'drive_mode': []}
  ]



def format_data_car(car_info):
    car_data = []
    get_values_for_keys = ['car', 'drive_mode']
    for step_name in car_info:
        for key, val in step_name.items():
            step_id_values = dict(filter(lambda item: item[0] in get_values_for_keys, step_name.items())).values()
            car_data.append(step_id_values)
            break
    filter_data = {}
    format_steps_ids = dict(car_data)
    for key, value in format_steps_ids.items():
        filter_data[key] = str(value)[2:-2]
    print(filter_data)
    return filter_data


def testing(source_info):
 d = defaultdict(list)
 for k, v in source_info.items():
  d[v].append(k)
 print(dict(d))


print(testing(format_data_car(car_info)))
```

How can I refactor my code function: `format_data_car(car_info)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is loop over every car, then for each drive mode it has, add that car to the dictionary's list for that drive mode. To do this, all you need is a simple nested for-loop and check if the `drive_mode` is empty:

```
import collections


def format_data(car_info):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for car in car_info:
        if not car['drive_mode']:
            d[''].append(car['car'])
        
        for drive_mode in car['drive_mode']:
            d[drive_mode].append(car['car'])
    return d
```

Comment: works 90% but fails for my new condition when drive_mode is empty..
{'car': 'bmw3', 'drive_mode': []}

Comment: @kumarRaj Ok, I've updated my code to work with it now. Can you try again?

Comment: instead of `if len(car['drive_mode']) == 0:`, one can also do `if car['drive_mode']:` since an empty list is considered false-y

Comment: @ificiana You're right! Thanks for the suggestion. However, I had to use `not car['drive_mode']` because I only want it to fire if the list is empty. Thanks!

Comment: @kumarRaj Does my updated code work for you?

Comment: @MichaelM. ah yes my bad, you're right

Comment: @MichaelM. Works Superbb!! Thanks making code look elegant know